# Django vs PostgreSQL: how to queue write and read?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, scheduled-tasks

I have got the following problem:
We have 3 components in the system - say, front-end, a Ruby app that deals with database write requests and a Django app that handles the read requests (from the same PostgreSQL database). At some point, the front-end updates (PUT) a record in the database via Ruby app and after that request, asynchronously sends another request to fetch the updated version of that record via Django app (GET). 
The problem is that the GET requests sometimes returns the old version of the record (not updated), that is, the Ruby app takes too long to update the database and before it is done, Django fetches the old version of the record.
I am aware that my server is too "weak" for this kind of job and with a proper serving computer it will be fine, but it is not 100% guaranteed.

I can think of few ways of dealing with that, just wondering if there is a proper way of fixing it?

Thanks!

P.S.: The Ruby and Django apps do not interact with each other and it is one of the important requirements!

Comment: Use `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` in the DB, so you tell the app about changes only once they're committed? Or have the Ruby app offer a way to wait until the commit succeeds and returns?

Comment: You could synchronise the requests in the client, retrying the Django GET until the correct version of the record is returned. Perhaps setting a last modified value or returning the PK of a new record would help. If neither the Ruby or Django apps interact then do it in the client.

Comment: Yeap, this is what I was thinking about AndrewS. I am sending the GET request and compare the value in the response with the correct one that I have got in the front-end. I send request every second until I get the correct value, which means that the record is updated.